# mysql: Finding a max in each column of a table

Tags: mysql

I have the table below.  I'm looking for the both the max value in each column AND it's matching username (all values of NULL to be ignored).
A bunch of mad googling has lead me to believe I need to find the max values and then use a second query to find the matching username?

But is there a query that can return this in one go?

```
ID   username    Vale   Jorge   Andrea
-------------------------------------------
01   John        2       6       NULL
02   Ted         NULL    0       0
03   Marcy       NULL    2       1

Output would be...
John Jorge 6
John Vale 2
Marcy Andrea 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one reasonably simple way of doing it... make a table of all the maximum values and join it to the usernames on matching the value with the max. Uses the fact that [`NULL` isn't equal to anything](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/working-with-null.html). I haven't attempted to order the results but that is easy enough with adding an `ORDER BY` clause.

```
select username, name, COALESCE(mv.vale, mv.jorge, mv.Andrea) as value 
from table1
join 
(select 'Vale' as name, max(vale) as vale, NULL as jorge, NULL as andrea from table1
union ALL
select 'Jorge', NULL, max(jorge), NULL from table1
union all
select 'Andrea', NULL, NULL, max(andrea) from table1) mv
on table1.vale = mv.vale or table1.jorge = mv.jorge or table1.andrea = mv.andrea
```

Output

```
 username   name    value   
 John       Vale    2
 John       Jorge   6
 Marcy      Andrea  1
```

To extrapolate this to more columns is reasonably straightforward (if somewhat painful) e.g. to add a column called fred you would use (changes inside **):

```
select username, name, COALESCE(mv.vale, mv.jorge, mv.Andrea**, mf.fred**) as value 
from table1
join 
(select 'Vale' as name, max(vale) as vale, NULL as jorge, NULL as andrea**, NULL as fred** from table1
union ALL
select 'Jorge', NULL, max(jorge), NULL**, NULL** from table1
union all
select 'Andrea', NULL, NULL, max(andrea)**, NULL** from table1) mv
**union all
select 'Fred', NULL, NULL, max(fred), NULL from table1) mf**
on table1.vale = mv.vale or table1.jorge = mv.jorge or table1.andrea = mv.andrea **or table1.fred = mf.fred**
```

If you have access to stored procedures, you can also do it like this (in a much more flexible way in terms of columns)

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS list_maxes;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE list_maxes(tname VARCHAR(20), column_list VARCHAR(1000))
BEGIN
    DECLARE maxv INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cpos INT;
    DECLARE colname VARCHAR(20);

    -- loop through the column names
    WHILE (LENGTH(column_list) > 0)
    DO
       SET cpos = LOCATE(',', column_list);
       IF (cpos > 0) THEN
           SET colname = LEFT(column_list, cpos - 1);
           SET column_list = SUBSTRING(column_list, cpos + 1);
       ELSE
           SET colname = column_list;
           SET column_list = '';
       END IF;

       -- find the maximum value of this column
       SET @getmax = CONCAT('SELECT MAX(', colname, ') INTO @maxv FROM Table1');
       PREPARE s1 FROM @getmax;
       EXECUTE s1;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE s1;

       -- now find the user with the maximum value
       SET @finduser = CONCAT("SELECT username, '", colname, "' AS name, ", colname, ' AS value FROM ', tname,' WHERE ', colname, ' = ', @maxv);
       PREPARE s2 FROM @finduser;
       EXECUTE s2;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE s2;
    END WHILE;
END//
DELIMITER ;
CALL list_maxes('table1', 'Vale,Jorge,Andrea')
```

Output

```
John       Vale    2
John       Jorge   6
Marcy      Andrea  1
```

Comment: Thanks Nick (and @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ) I gave this a go and it worked a treat.  Now i have to get my head around how it actually works as i'm a nube.. ..and extrapolate it to the 25 colums I have.
~ laughs ~

Comment: I've made an edit to indicate how to add an extra column. You can follow that pattern to add all of them... it'll be a bit painful but will work. In terms of figuring out how it works, take a look at the pieces one by one: the unions, then the join without the on condition, and then the query as a whole. Good luck! And if this did help, it'd be great if you could mark it accepted.

Comment: Done..
and thanks to the folk who gave other answers too.

Comment: John - added a stored procedure version which could make your life easier in terms of having 25 columns to process.

Answer (score 1):

There's different ways of looking at it, here's a table that gives a row for each username that has a matching max value:

```
SELECT
   username
 , IF (max_vale = t.vale, max_vale, NULL) AS for_vale
 , IF (max_jorge = t.jorge, max_jorge, NULL) AS for_jorge
 , IF (max_andrea = t.andrea, max_andrea, NULL) AS for_andrea
FROM (
   SELECT 
      MAX(vale) AS max_vale
    , MAX(jorge) AS max_jorge
    , MAX(andrea) AS max_andrea
   FROM t
) y
JOIN t ON (
  t.vale = max_vale
  OR t.jorge = max_jorge
  OR t.andrea = max_andrea
)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58e37d/5

This gives:

```
username    for_vale    for_jorge   for_andrea
----------------------------------------------
John        2           6           (null)
Marty       (null)      (null)      1
```

Basically, all I'm doing is selecting the specific column max values, then using that query as the source for another query that just looks at the `MAX` generated columns, and filters (`IF()`) based on the matches found.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite long but working. I combine all columns into one table using UNION ALL. Then get the max value per surname. Join this to the original table using the surname and value. Order by value in descending order.

```
select tv.*
from( select surname, max(val) as maxval
   from (
          select username,'vale' as surname,vale as val
         from tbl
         union all
         select username,'jorge' as surname,jorge
         from tbl
         union all
         select username,'andrea' as surname,andrea
         from tbl) tab
         group by surname) tt
         join (
            select username,'vale' as surname,vale as val
            from tbl
            union all
            select username,'jorge' as surname,jorge
            from tbl
           union all
           select username,'andrea' as surname,andrea
           from tbl) tv
       on tt.surname=tv.surname and tt.maxval=tv.val
       order by tv.val desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

As a whole other way to resolve the request, we may look at the model, e.g., the fact that what appears to be domain content is represented as columns instead of rows. This is typical of a source aggregate query (pivot or rollup to get aggregated totals or groupings, for instance), but if the underlying data spreads out, should perhaps be based on the transactional integrity of that data source (the "spread out" underlying source).

Basically, I wonder why there are `Vale`, `Jorge` and `Andrea` columns at all in the database. This implies it's already been summarized.

So we may look at an alternate model that is notably easier to navigate for these purposes:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prospect` (
  `id` MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `aggregate` (
  `id` MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `prospect_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `total` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

SELECT
   user.username
 , prospect.name
 , MAX(aggregate.total) AS max_aggregate
FROM aggregate
JOIN user ON user_id = user.id
JOIN prospect ON prospect_id = prospect.id
GROUP BY username
```

This produces:

```
John    Andrea  6
Marty   Jorge   2
Ted     Jorge   5
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/07ba0c/1

This may not be useful to you now, but as your experience grows and your experience with advanced querying evolves, this will make more sense. The main difficulty may be that the core data is already turned, making the querying more difficult because what you want is a different [dimension than what you may have already derived](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP_cube).